# Сделать форму на VBA

Tags: visual-basic

Вот сама задача:

[image: img]
не могу найти формулу расчета Х

Comment: а самой первой строкой что написано?

Comment: [Нажми сюда, если не боишься][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Screen

Comment: @samoilow, комп мог быть в аудитории без выхода в интернет и с заклеенными USB-портами )

Comment: @Nofate, точно, извиняюсь-с.

Comment: Проблема в выражении икса.
Как в VBA забить

Answer (score 1):

x = φ ( x )

Подробности знает Вики: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8